# Can you set an inferior limit to scale breaks on ggplot with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating histograms for different categories of a variable, and separating them through `facet_wrap`, with `scales = 'free'`. This works for most of the categories, but for one of them the bar never goes above 1, and so the scale broken in intervals of 0.25, which doesn't make sense for a histogram.

Is there a way to set up the plot so that the interval between breaks never goes below 1? on some other categories the bar goes up to 300 so I can't just set `breaks` manually.

I can't share the data but made an example data frame:

```
class = c(rep(1,200), rep(2,200), rep(3,200))
x = c(rnorm(200, mean = 5, sd = 1), rnorm(200, 5, 4), rnorm(200, 5, 9))
df = data.frame(x, class)
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x))+
  geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = 'steelblue', binwidth = 1)+
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = 'free')
```

producing the following histogram:
[example histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12r1e.png)

Let's say that in this example, I didn't want the scale intervals to go below 10 (so plots for class 2 and 3 would have `breaks = seq(0,100,10)` but wanted to do that whitout affecting the scale of the plot for class == 1. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: IMO this is something that should be solved on the data level, not plotting. Perhaps adding an arbitrary number to values in classes that go below your threshold?

Comment: histograms represent density not frequency, so divisions of less than one do make sense.

Comment: no, histograms represent frequency, they are different from density plots.

Comment: From the [wikipedia page for histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram): "Histograms give a rough sense of the density of the underlying distribution of the data, and often for density estimation: estimating the probability density function of the underlying variable". By definition they are for density estimation. However they are often misused for frequencies.

Comment: They are used to have a rough sense of the probability density, but most often don't actually represent it (as is my case). 

That's because the columns on the histogram still represent the frequency, to represent density, the columns would have to be adjusted as to guarantee the area of the histogram adds up to 1, as is said next to the text you quoted: " The total area of a histogram used for probability density is always normalized to 1."

It's a small difference, but that's why in my case divisions of less than 1 don't make sense, since I'm not normalizing the plot or estimating densit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `facetted_pos_scales` function from the `ggh4x` package for this.  So for your toy example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
class = c(rep(1,200), rep(2,200), rep(3,200))
x = c(rnorm(200, mean = 5, sd = 1), rnorm(200, 5, 4), rnorm(200, 5, 9))
df = data.frame(x, class)
df |> ggplot(aes(x = x))+
  geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = 'steelblue', binwidth = 1)+
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = 'free') + 
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      class %in% c("2","3") ~ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))
      )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked pretty well. Do you know of any packages to do the same thing but for plot attributes? (color, fill, barwidth, number of bins, etc)

Comment: Personally if I wanted all these things to be different I would use patchwork to stitch plots together rather than facets.  Having said that `ggh4x` seems to deal with color scales as well https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ggh4x/vignettes/Miscellaneous.html